# How to replace redirectStrategy in ConcurrentSessionFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Im using Spring Security 3.2.7. The existing ConcurrentSessionFilter is redirecting the request when the sessionExpires. I would like to change and forward that request to a custom controller. How can I achieve this ? 
I configured ConcurrentSessionFilter manually and added it in Spring config. This results in calling the filter twice.

Below is the spring security config :

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentSessionFilter getConcurrentSessionFilter() {
    RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new 
    CustomSessionRedirectStrategy(true, false);
    ConcurrentSessionFilter concurrentSessionFilter = new ConcurrentSessionFilter(getSessionRegistry(),SESSION_EXPIRED_REDIRECT_END_POINT);

    concurrentSessionFilter.setRedirectStrategy(redirectStrategy);
    concurrentSessionFilter.afterPropertiesSet();

    return concurrentSessionFilter;
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    /****/
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
    .maximumSessions(1)
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
    .sessionRegistry(getSessionRegistry())

    .and()
        /****/
    .addFilterBefore(getConcurrentSessionFilter(), ConcurrentSessionFilter.class)
        /***/
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *As you can see, I havent configured a custom filter. Im reusing the ConcurrentSessionFilter provided by spring* That's completly wrong, you created a custom one with  `new ConcurrentSessionFilter(getSessionRegistry(),SESSION_EXPIRED_REDIRECT_END_POINT);` You didn't reuse the default one. Hence, your custom filter is called and the default filter is called. Resulting in two different filter calls.

Comment: @dur .. ok. my mistake. So how can I use the custom one only or wire the redirectStrategy to the default one .

Comment: I don't know any easy way. The configuration [`SessionManagementConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.html) is limited to some properties.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I was not able to wire the redirectStrategy. Is there any way to replace the default one with the custom way. ? Im all ears for a way.

Comment: i have the same problem with the FormLoginConfigurer, i want to change the redirectStrategy, did you find any solution?